# Spring Cache Hit Flag/Indicator

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I am  using Spring Cache to cache some objects through @Cacheable. However, 1 of the requirement requires me to be able to know if the returned object was from the Cache Hit or standard call. Is there any flag or indicator thats gets set i can use to check this ?

I have seen past questions regarding cache hits being logged whenever there are cache hits but that is not really useful for my situation. I am currently using Spring Cache with the Simple Provider and am open to using any external Cache Managers that is able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can know whether it is a cache hit or a cache miss(a direct call to REST call or a database call) using a flag.

Using `@Cacheable`, it always first checks in the cache, before it executes the method, if found in cache, it will skip the method execution, where as `@CachePut` works slightly different, where it will executes the adivised method & updates the cache, so it will miss the cache always.

For example:

```
    private volatile boolean cacheMiss = false;

    public boolean isCacheMiss(){
        boolean cacheMiss = this.cacheMiss;
        this.cacheMiss = false; //resetting for next read
        return cacheMiss;
    }

    protected void setCacheMiss(){
        this.cacheMiss = true;
    }

  
    @Cacheable("Quotes")
    public Quote requestQuote(Long id) {
        setCacheMiss();
       //REST CALL HERE
        return requestQuote(ID_BASED_QUOTE_SERVICE_URL,
                      Collections.singletonMap("id", id));
    }
```

`cacheMiss` variable gives the status, whether it is from cache or not.

Here is it discussed [Spring Caching with GemFire](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching-gemfire/), the underlying caching provider is Pivotal GemFire. You can use any such caching providers.